# Need to write condition in build.gradle , if that satisfies it should download dependencies from specific artifactory

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, release

I am setting up new gradle project and want to write a condition in build.gradle so that it should download dependency from certain artifactory if that condition satisfies.

I am using `project.hasProperty("property")` and my repositories block is as follows.

````
    mavenCentral()
    if(project.hasProperty("isRelease")){
        println("Inside gradle")
        maven { url 'release url' }
    } else {
        println("Inside snapshot")
        maven { url 'snapshot url' }
    }
    mavenLocal()
}```
````

Comment: And? What is your question?

Comment: It is not working as it never finds the property. Can you please tell me how should I achieve it ?

Comment: And *how* do you provide the property to the project? Tell precisely what you're doing.

Comment: ```./gradlew -PisRelease Release``` like this

Comment: Post a complete minimal example reproducing the error. I've tried it like that, but probably made incorrect assumptions based on what you posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pass it like this:

```
-PisRelease=Release
```

I've tried in this code:

```
repositories {

    if(project.isRelease == "Release"){
        println("I'm in")
    }

    mavenLocal()
}
```

and worked properly.

[image]

**UPDATE** with the solution talked in the comment about checking the version property directly. I,ve put the version in the build.gradle but works with the version in *gradle.properties* too

*build.gradle*

```
version="1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    if (isRelease()){
        maven { url 'release url' }
    } else {
        maven { url 'snapshot url' }
    }
    mavenLocal()
}

def isRelease() {
    if(project.version.contains("SNAPSHOT")){
        println("Is a SNAPSHOT")
    } else if(!project.version.contains("SNAPSHOT") || project.version.contains("RC")){
        println("Is Release")
    }
}
```

You can of course, modify the `isRelease` logic with the one you need. Is just an example.

Hope it helps

Comment: Is there any other way, by which I don't need to pass it as property?

Comment: Yes, but is just a guess that you want like check if your version has this 'Release' literal... is that correct? I can update my answer if you confirm this

Comment: isRelease is a variable sent by end user through jenkinsfile to tell jenkins if this is a release build and if this is a release build it should not download dependencies from gradle snapshot url. Please let me know how can I achieve it?

Comment: Why do that? Is not better just figure this out with the version property? Doing the isRelease approach could be a double maitaining problem. What if the user forgets to change the SNAPSHOT version but activates the isRelease flag or the other way, puts a release versions but forgets to put the isRelease flag to true. I'll just check the version property and activate the repos with this. What do you think?

Comment: I've updated the solution, check in the UPDATE and let me know if works for you

Comment: Earlier solution helped me. thanks for the update. @dcalap